# DB2 SQL - Set variable value based on user input

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

In DB2-LUW SQL, I can write a query to do this:

```
select * from customers
&input
```

When a user runs that they'll be prompted for input and can type:

```
where name = 'Bill'
```

And the query that actually gets executed will be:

```
select * from customers
where name = 'Bill'
```

I am trying to figure out a way to vary the value of `&input` to alter the query based on more basic user input - so they won't need to type in `where name = 'Bill'`.

For example, the user could be prompted to enter either `YesBill` or `NoBill` and depending on what they've entered, the value of `&input` will be set and the executed query would be either:

```
select * from customers
where name = 'Bill'
```

or

```
select * from customers
where name <> 'Bill'
```

The example is meaningless, I'm mostly wondering if it's possible to vary the value  of `&input` without forcing the user to type in SQL code.

Hope that makes sense.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: The typical way you would want to expose a SQL query to the outside world is via a prepared statement.  You would use a placeholder for the name, e.g. something like this: `SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = ?`.  The `?` gets filled with some sterilized value from the outside world.

Comment: Thanks for responding Tim!  The situation I'm in is a bit unusual as my audience is users who have access to an application in which they are allowed to write and run their own queries, but a lot of them don't know anything about SQL and aren't going to learn.  I don't really have a front end that I can put this behind, and I'm searching for a way to make it as easy as possible for the users and the query/procedure will do all the work.

Comment: It will depend on the front-end tech stack you are using too.  This is how I do a DB2 query in .NET with a parameter.  This uses a session, but it could be querystring, textbox, or other input:   SelectCommand="SELECT OI.ORDERS_ID, OI.PARTNUM, CE.FIELD4, OI.PRICE, OI.QUANTITY, OI.STATUS, OI.TOTALPRODUCT, OI.TOTALADJUSTMENT
  FROM DB2ADMIN.ORDERITEMS OI INNER JOIN DB2ADMIN.CATENTRY CE ON OI.CATENTRY_ID = CE.CATENTRY_ID WHERE OI.ORDERS_ID = @OrdersID">        <SelectParameters>            <asp:SessionParameter Name="OrdersID" SessionField="ORDERS_ID" Type="Int64" />        </SelectParameters>

Comment: Also worth noting - input parameters work fine, where the statment would be `select * from customers where name = &name`.  I'm trying to vary the `where` clause itself: `select * from customers &input`

Comment: This doesn't look like valid SQL syntax; are you talking about `clpplus` parameters, may be? Or some other client software that you use to run your queries?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question really depends on the SQL client that you are using.

For example, if you use DBeaver, then you can simply use `:` to prefix your variable names and then when executing the query, you will get a prompt to window to enter your variable names.

Other query tools may, nor may not, provide a similar capability

[image]